# My Form is not registering Enter key presses

Tags: vb.net, keydown, enter, acceptbutton

I am writing an educational program. I have a button which I want to be **"clicked"** when the user presses enter. I have set the form's accept button property to true and the KeyPreview property is also set to true. I have tried creating a custom Sub to replicate AcceptButton functionality, this does not work either, the sub runs on all keys other than when the enter key is pressed.

```
    Private Sub TextBoxAnswer_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBoxAnswer.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Enter Then
            CheckQ()
        End If
     End Sub
```

I have spent the last 3 days searching for an answer and have tried everything on google I could find. I have also just tried setting the textbox `MultiLine` property to true and the enter key doesn't even create a new line, just to clarify I have set the `Multiline` property back to false now as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

The `AcceptButton` property should be set = to the button you want "clicked" when enter is pressed, not a boolean value. `Me.AcceptButton = buttonSubmit`

Did you add a handler for the form's Keydown event to go along with setting the KeyPreview property?

```
Private Sub form1_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles form1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Enter Then
        CheckQ()
        e.Handled = true
    End If
 End Sub
```

Your code as you have it written for the textbox keydown event should work as well.  I tried it in a test app and didn't have any issues.  Do you hit a breakpoint if you place it on the CheckQ() method call?

Any one of these methods should accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, sorry typing mistake the Accept button is set to a button called ButtonCheck, Thanks for any more help. I hit no breakpoint when I did what you describe and the code you posted also didn't work, many thanks though.

Comment: I have also checked that when the enter key is pressed no breakpoints are hit anywhere in the sub

Comment: I created a test app and was able to catch the enter key using the `AcceptButton` property, the `KeyDown` event on the form after setting `KeyPreview = true` and using the `KeyDown` event on the text box.  Can you post more of your code?

Comment: The total solution is **just** under 10,000 lines long which bit do you want

Comment: I'd want to just see the code that is in the form that is pertinent to your question.  What I'd recommend you try doing is create a test application and see if you can get it working there.  If you can then compare your test app to your other application and look for differences that could effect it's ability to catch the enter key being pressed.

Comment: I have created a test program and I have got it to work in there, and I have compared what I could see could affect this but I couldn't see anything obvious. Can you give me any more suggestions of things that could affect this for me to investigate, thanks.

Comment: I have just commented out all code in the form and run the app and the enter key is still not registered!

Comment: @user2756856 - Does the button click event fire when you actually click the button with the mouse?  Is the click event of the button wired up properly?

Comment: Yes the code in the `CheckQ()` sub runs as it should on the button click

Comment: After creating a new window within the same project the enter key was not registered in the new form either. So the problem is project wide.

Comment: I have just created a sub which has `Handles` on the `KeyDown` event of all the controls on the form, and when the enter key is pressed nothing on the form receives the enter key press, so the key press isn't being 'stolen' from something within the form.